# Euler Method - Why is my intuition incorrect?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{dA}{dt} = 0.5 \times A \times (1 - \dfrac{A}{100}) - 10$$ with $A(0) = 70$ and we want to use Euler's method to get an approximate value for $A(10)$, with a step size of 1.

So the answer sheet says you basically have to use $\text{Ans} +  0.5 \times \text{Ans} \times (1-\dfrac{\text{Ans}}{100}) - 10$ with the first $\text{Ans}$ being $70$, and then of course repeat 10 times.

But I'm wondering, doesn't this actually give you $\dfrac{dA(10)}{dt}$? How is this a correct method?

Comment: @Amzoti My question is in the last sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler method does not give you $\frac {dA}{dt}$.  You give it a formula for $\frac {dA}{dt}$, such as the one in your question.  Then from any given point, like your start of $(0,70)$ it puts a straight line through the point with slope $\frac {dA}{dt}$ of that point.  From your expression, $\frac {dA}{dt}|_{(0,70)}=0.5$ so we step one unit in $t$ at a slope of $0.5$, giving the $A$ value of the next point as $70+0.5\cdot 1=70.5$.  Now we are at $(70.5,1)$, we calculate $\frac {dA}{dt}$ at this point and take another step along the $t$ axis, and so on until we get to $t=10$

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is wrong.  If the differential equation is $\dfrac{dA}{dt} = f(A)$ and your step size is $h$, the formula is $A_{n+1} = A_n + h f(A_n)$.
So in this case, $A_n + 0.5 A_n (1 - A_n/100) - 10$.

Comment: But this still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: ${dA}{dt} = f(A)$.  This isn't the same as $A + h f(A)$.

Comment: It's just from the correction sheet, I'm not really worrying about it in this question, my worry is: How does this method give you $A(10)$? It seems to me it gives you the derivative at $A(10)$. Or are you supposed to just use that value you get, plug it in and solve for $A$?

Comment: It gives you an approximation for $A(10)$.  It doesn't give you the derivative there, that's $f(A(10))$.